# Unknown Property:"-fx-background-color"

Tags: java, css, javafx

I am a beginner in JavaFX and this warning occurs every time whenever I'm trying to write any CSS code in JavaFX:

```css
.buttons{
    -fx-background-color: black;
}
```

It is giving me a warning as **Unknown Property:-fx-background-color** ,and not only for the background color, it pops up in all cases.

Comment: Whose giving the warning? If it's your IDE then it could just be your IDE doesn't recognize JavaFX CSS but it should still work when running your application. However, the use of `.buttons` seems a little suspicious. Are you sure you don't mean `.button`?

Comment: Slaw my Pane contains total of 6 buttons thats why I was using '.buttons' instead of '.button', but thanks buddy. I removed the bug

Answer (score 0):

You might Forget to add JavaFX SDK.Right click on your project and go to build path > Configure build path. Under libraries, click on "Add library." button. Add JavaFX SDK to your project.It work to me.